# How can I process the latest Kafka message (by custom comparator) per key every X minutes?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to write a Kafka Consumer that processes the latest record of a Kafka topic every X (5) minutes.
Latest being defined by an internal version field, and not the Kafka timestamp.

The best way I found after researching is KStreams, using the processor API.

```
public class LatestProcessor implements Processor<Long, Dto> {
    private ProcessorContext context = null;
    private KeyValueStore<Long, Dto> kvStore;

    public LatestProcessor () {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore(Config.stateStore);
        this.context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(5)), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, this::punctuate);
    }


    @Override
    public void process(Long key, Dto message) {
        Dto current = kvStore.get(key);
        if (current == null || current.version() <= message.version()) {
              kvStore.put(key, message);
        }
    }


    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
        // processes all the messages in the state
        KeyValueIterator<Long, Dto> iter = this.kvStore.all();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            KeyValue<Long, Dto> entry = iter.next();
            context.forward(entry.key, entry.value);
            kvStore.delete(entry.key);
        }
        iter.close();
        context.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Within this Processor example:

1. Once we have called `ProcessorContext::forward`, is the key guaranteed to go to the next step? i.e. context.forward cannot fail after we delete the key from the store.
2. Is the only way for this to be Fault-Tolerant to emit directly into another Kafka Sink? If we fail and rebuild the state store, we might have deleted a key.
3. Can the state store be built `withLoggingDisabled()`? Since we commit manually, is there a risk of KStream committing before we commit in `punctuate()`?

If you have other ideas please let me know. I know that Kafka spark would work, but spark is not the preferred framework.

I tried using DSL

```
KStream<Long, Dto> stream;
stream
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(5), Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .emitStrategy(EmitStrategy.onWindowClose())
    .reduce(...)
```

but this did not produce the behavior I expected, I think it was using the Kafka timestamp time and producing inconsistent windows.

Comment: Last I checked, any Kafka Stream window is going to use a TimestampExtractor, not based on any other record information, so therefore, sounds like a session window with a timeout might be better. Otherwise, I don't think Kafka Streams is the best solution for this problem. E.g. Kafka Connect could dump to a database, where you could order/limit by any field you wanted